# Shiny: Improve / format text output of verbatimTextOutput()

Tags: r, text, shiny, formatting, output

I have

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Interactive CLicks"),   
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    verbatimTextOutput("info_hover"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot",hover = "plot_hover",click= "plot_click", dblclick = "plot_db_click",height = 500, width = 1600 ),
    br(),
    verbatimTextOutput("info_click"),
    verbatimTextOutput("info_db_click"),    
    verbatimTextOutput("double_to_single_click"))
  
)




## server.R
server <- function( input, output, session){
  
  #Click Points
  single.source_coords <- reactiveValues(xy=data.frame(x=c(1,1),  y=c(1,1)))
  double.source_coords <- reactiveValues(xy=data.frame(x=c(1,1),  y=c(1,1)))
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    single.source_coords$xy[2,] <- c(input$plot_click$x, input$plot_click$y)
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_db_click, {
    double.source_coords$xy[2,] <- c(input$plot_db_click$x, input$plot_db_click$y)
  })
  
  
  ## RenderPlot 
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ 
    plot(1, 1,
         xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
    
    #Click points
    points( single.source_coords$xy[2,1], single.source_coords$xy[2,2], cex=3, pch=17)
    points( double.source_coords$xy[2,1], double.source_coords$xy[2,2], cex=3, pch=17)
    segments(x0 =single.source_coords$xy[2,1], y0 = single.source_coords$xy[2,2], x1 =  double.source_coords$xy[2,1], y1 = double.source_coords$xy[2,2], col = "darkred", lwd = 2, lty = 3)
    
    
  })        
  
  output$info_click <- renderText({
    paste0("Single Click Multiple", "\nX=", single.source_coords$xy[2,1], "     Y= ",single.source_coords$xy[2,2], "\nX=", round(single.source_coords$xy[2,1],4), "     Y= ",round(single.source_coords$xy[2,2], 5))
  })
  
  output$info_db_click <- renderText({
    paste0("Double  Multiple", "\nX=", double.source_coords$xy[2,1], "     Y= ",double.source_coords$xy[2,2], "\nX=", round(double.source_coords$xy[2,1],2), "     Y= ",round(double.source_coords$xy[2,2],4))
  })
  
  output$info_hover <- renderText({
    paste0("Hover  Multiple", "\nX=", input$plot_hover$x*2, "     Y= ",input$plot_hover$y*2,  "\nThis is X=", round(input$plot_hover$x*2,5), "   not A but Y= ",round(input$plot_hover$y*2,4))
  })
  
  
  
  
}

### Run Application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the 3 output areas of `verbatimTextOutput()` because of the different length of the labels and the outputs the result of the `verbatimTextOutput()` looks awful

[image]

Is there any way to align Labels and Outputs so that it is more aesthetically pleasing? I like the compactness of `verbatimTextOutput()` I would not like to go to a table output. I would just like to find a way to improve the formatting of `verbatimTextOutput()`.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `sprintf` instead of `paste0` to create formatted strings, indicating spacing, # of digits for floating point values, etc. Have you considered/tried that?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Instead of `paste0("Single Click Multiple", "\nX=", single.source_coords$xy[2,1]...` you can try `sprintf("Single Click HERE\nX: %4.2f Y: %4.2f", single.source_coords$xy[2,1], single.source_coords$xy[2,2])` ... you can indicate how much space numbers take up, number of decimal places, etc. See [this](https://statisticsglobe.com/sprintf-r-function-example) for some examples, or [this](https://r-lang.com/sprintf-function-in-r-with-example/) for a quick tutorial, or [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) for details...

Comment: Thanks Ben. I'll try to make it work. I was hoping for something less laborious ...